# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte inside a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

There are already similar questions around here. In my eyes the following question is different because I have a dictionary and not a string.

So, I have a dict: `result_dict`. Some of values inside this dictionary may contain ü, ä, ß etc.

When I try to dump this dict using:

```
result_dict_dumped = json.dumps(result_dict)
```

I receive this error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 9: invalid start byte
```

Is there any opportunity to solve this problem without taking every single value inside the dictionary and encoding it ?

Here's a small example dictionary:

```
{
    'POSSIBLE_DATACENTER': 'tt@4', 
    'CPU_COUNT': None, 
    'DESCRIPTION': 'Test-DC f\xfcr tbc'
}
```

The `f\xfcr` is actually `für`

Comment: What Python version are you using? Unicode handling in Python 3 is somewhat different to how it works in Python 2. You should post a small example of your dictionary.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. Example of the content of the dictionary: {'POSSIBLE_DATACENTER': 'tt@4', 'CPU_COUNT': None, 'DESCRIPTION': 'Test-DC f\xfcr tbc'}. f\xfcr is actualy "für".

Comment: json is a text-based format, it cannot be used to represent arbitrary byte sequences. What encoding is your dict data using?

Comment: I dont'know the encoding format of dict data

Comment: @TomDalton: My guess (from the example data) is that the encoding is latin1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is a text-based format, it cannot be used to represent arbitrary byte sequences. What encoding is your dict data using - the byte 0xfc is not a valid 1-byte utf-8 character.

You'll probably need to decode the contents of your dict (from whatever encoding it's currently stored in), before you try to json-encode it.

Edit: Your dict data encoding *might* be any of the following encodings:

```
>>> x = b"\xfc"
>>> print x.decode("latin-1")
ü
>>> print x.decode("cp1252")
ü

>>> json.dumps(x.decode("latin-1"))
'"\\u00fc"'
```

You call also tell the json encoder that strings are in different encoding to utf-8 - this is probably what you'll want to do, as long as every str in your dict is in this encoding:

```
>>> json.dumps(b"\xfc", encoding="latin-1")
'"\\u00fc"'
```

Comment: "latin-1" is an alias for ["ISO-8859-1"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Comment: Ok. Do i understand right that i have to run over the content of my dict and encode everything in the right format and put it in a new dict?

Comment: See my last edit at the bottom - you can pass the codec name to json.dump and it will do that for you - as long as every string in the input doct is in that encoding!

Comment: It works!!! thanks!!!! `json.dumps(result_dict, encoding="latin-1")` worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are running python2 - you need to use the decode method...

Small example - sorry using your letters....

```
import pprint
gstr_in_bytes=bytearray(b'ü'+b'ä'+b'ß')
type(gstr_in_bytes)

print("Data looks like this")
pprint.pprint(gstr_in_bytes)
print("String in utf8 is %s"%gstr_in_bytes.decode('utf-8'))
```

You should be seeing

```
Data looks like this
bytearray(b'\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa4\xc3\x9f')
String in utf8 is üäß
```

Answer (score 1):

Tom has answered your question but you may find the output of this code interesting. Note that my terminal is configured to use UTF-8 encoding.

```
import json

d = {
    'POSSIBLE_DATACENTER': 'tt@4', 
    'CPU_COUNT': None, 
    'DESCRIPTION': 'Test-DC f\xfcr tbc'
}

def show_dict(d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        print k, v

print '*** Original ***'
show_dict(d)

print '\n*** Decoded from latin1 ***'
s = json.dumps(d, encoding='latin1', indent=4)
print s

newd = json.loads(s)
print '\n*** Reloaded ***'
show_dict(newd)

print '\n*** new dump ***'
print json.dumps(newd, indent=4)
```

**output**

```
*** Original ***
POSSIBLE_DATACENTER tt@4
CPU_COUNT None
DESCRIPTION Test-DC f�r tbc

*** Decoded from latin1 ***
{
    "POSSIBLE_DATACENTER": "tt@4", 
    "CPU_COUNT": null, 
    "DESCRIPTION": "Test-DC f\u00fcr tbc"
}

*** Reloaded ***
POSSIBLE_DATACENTER tt@4
CPU_COUNT None
DESCRIPTION Test-DC für tbc

*** new dump ***
{
    "POSSIBLE_DATACENTER": "tt@4", 
    "CPU_COUNT": null, 
    "DESCRIPTION": "Test-DC f\u00fcr tbc"
}
```

You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.